# Why does Postgresql Data directory revert to default after updates/reboots?

Tags: bash, postgresql

I have something that is pretty simple to explain. We have certain server builds as it relates to directories in our CentOS boxes at my company and so to accommodate those, I have a script that changes the PostgreSQL data directory. However, there seem to be some occasions where it reverts back to the default value. I know one such instance was after our IT department did some upgrades and then rebooted. I can't say for sure what exactly does this, but let me show you the code that I use to change the data directory and maybe someone can figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
sed -i "s/Environment=PGDATA=\/var\/lib\/pgsql\/11\/data/Environment=PGDATA=\/usr\/local\/pgsql\/data/" /usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-11.service

systemctl daemon-reload

systemctl restart postgresql-11
```

There is more, but that is what changes the data directory. Any ideas why this randomly will switch back to /var/lib/pgsql/11/data and how I can prevent this from changing back? My guess is that I need to change it somewhere other than just the service file, but I have yet to find out where else I need to change it.

I guess it could help if I provided some information. This is on a CentOS 7 box, with Postgresql 11.

Comment: You probably don't want to be changing the file in `/usr/lib`, but putting something in `/etc/systemd/`. See any guide to systemd for details. Upgrading packages is likely to revert your changes. Then check your postgresql configuration flles too (either `/etc/postgresql/` or in your data dir itself.)

Comment: I should mention, they were not upgrading PostgreSQL itself. At least, if they were, they mostly definitely should be as that lies in my departments realm. And from what I can tell, they didn't either. I can look at the /etc/systemd thing.

Answer (score 2):

After looking up some more details. It seems that the better options is create an override file in /etc/systemd .

Though, I cannot vouch for if this is best practice, I believe that it is a better option since I do not have to edit the default file.

```
dir=/etc/systemd/system/postgresql-11.service.d
if [ ! -d $dir ]
then
    mkdir $dir
    chmod 755 $dir
fi
cd $dir
touch override.conf
echo '[Service]' >> override.conf
echo 'Environment=PGDATA=/usr/local/pgsql/data' >> override.conf
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart postgresql-11
```

I know normally this is done via systemctl edit, but from what i can tell, this does the same thing, just without using systemctl. This DID work and it allowed postgres to work even though the data directory in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-11.service` does not have a working data directory in it. If someone has a better answer, I can gladly accept that though.

I arrived at this solution based off
https://pgstef.github.io/2018/02/28/custom_pgdata_with_systemd.html

Comment: works like a charm!